# Spliting Dictionary in Ansible based on condition

Tags: python, ansible

I am using ansible to get data from prometheus in OpenShift environment. I am creating a dictionary like the following output. Now I intend to split this dictionary into three separate dictionaries each for master,worker and infra nodes based on their hostnames.

I tried something like this but it fails.

```
- name: Seperate Dictionary Creation
  set_fact:
          master_nodes: "{{ master_nodes | combine( when: item.key == '*.master.*') }} "
  with_dict: "{{ all_host_dict }}"
```

Ansible Dictionary output

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": {
        "machine-worker01": {
            "cpu_percent": 0.5,
            "cpu_total": 12,
            "cpu_used": 0.06     
        },
        "machine-master01": {
            "cpu_percent": 0.58,
            "cpu_total": 12,
            "cpu_used": 0.07
        },
        "machine-master03": {
            "cpu_percent": 0.58,
            "cpu_total": 12,
            "cpu_used": 0.07
        },
        "machine-infra01": {
            "cpu_percent": 0.5,
            "cpu_total": 12,
            "cpu_used": 0.06
        },
        "machine-worker07": {
            "cpu_percent": 0.58,
            "cpu_total": 12,
            "cpu_used": 0.07
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a valid YAML. Without the commas `},` I'd say it's a dictionary. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```yaml
- name: Seperate Dictionary Creation
  set_fact:
    master_nodes: "{{ (master_nodes | default({})) | combine({item.key: item.value}) }}"
  when: item.key is search(".*master.*")
  with_dict: "{{ all_host_dict }}"
```

Also the regex should be modified from `*.master.*` to `.*master.*`.

Answer (score 1):

The tasks

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_nodes: "{{ my_nodes|default({})|
                      combine({(item ~ '_nodes'):
                               all_host_dict|dict2items|
                               selectattr('key', 'search', item)|
                               list|items2dict}) }}"
      loop: [master, worker, infra]
    - debug:
        var: my_nodes
```

give

```yaml
    "my_nodes": {
        "infra_nodes": {
            "machine-infra01": {
                "cpu_percent": 0.5,
                "cpu_total": 12,
                "cpu_used": 0.06
            }
        },
        "master_nodes": {
            "machine-master01": {
                "cpu_percent": 0.58,
                "cpu_total": 12,
                "cpu_used": 0.07
            },
            "machine-master03": {
                "cpu_percent": 0.58,
                "cpu_total": 12,
                "cpu_used": 0.07
            }
        },
        "worker_nodes": {
            "machine-worker01": {
                "cpu_percent": 0.5,
                "cpu_total": 12,
                "cpu_used": 0.06
            },
            "machine-worker07": {
                "cpu_percent": 0.58,
                "cpu_total": 12,
                "cpu_used": 0.07
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your approach is really great sir.